# Accessing a variable inside a Factory's callback function outside of it in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

My Factory looks like this:

```
.factory('MyFactory', function(){
    return: {
         someFunction: functon(firstParam, secondParam, resultObject) {
                     $http.get(url).success(resultObject);
        }     
    }
})
```

My controller looks like this:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    MyFactory.someFunction(paramOne, paramTwo, function(resultObj) {
          $scope.result = resultObj;
          console.log($scope.result) //has the object
     });
    console.log($scope.result) //undefined
}):
```

I'd like `$scope.result` to be available inside the controller and not just within the callback. Right now its only available within the callback function.

I understand what the problem is here, that the scope of the variable inside the callback function ends within the function, I just don't understand how to overcome this.

Comment: You can't do this, because the callback is asynchronous. In addition, you should return a promise from the factory, and call `success` or `then` inside the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that the scope of the variable is within the callback function, the problem is that while you do console.log($scope.result) outside the function inside the controller the $http request has not been completed so it will be undefined.

Once the request is complete you can access $scope.result within the controller.  The best way to solve this is to ensure that the $http request is finished before your controller even loads and this is possible through use of the resolve function in the routes.  You would fire off the $http request and wait for it to complete before even loading the route, so the result could be directly injected into the controller.

Here is a link that explains this concept: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

Comment: What if I need to use data from the controller while making the $http request? Like parts of the url for the request come from my controller. Is there a way to use data from the controller in a resolve function?

Comment: You would need to return a promise from the service and put your code in the .then() function.  Or you could return the $http call directly and put your code inside the .success() function.  This is a blog that explains promises nicely: http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html